# Error Broken Pipe by Pushing Git Gogs in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, gogs

When I try to push my code from eclipse 4.22.0 to local git server, come error messege

```
Can't connect to any repository: http://192.168.0.100:3000/root/ABC (http://192.168.0.100:3000/root/ABC: Broken pipe)
```

I cannot push to the lcoal git server. But this error will not come when I push files one by one.

I tried to run `git config --global http.postBuffer 52428800` on server throught cmd but nothing changes.

Client : MacOS with Eclipse 4.22.0

Server : Windows 10

git version 2.34.1.windows.1 with gogs

do anyone know, how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I updated

- eclipse to version 2022-03-R
- Git to version 2.35.3
- Change to Gitea 1.65.5

And the issue solved.

Hopefully this can help.